# How to deploy a JDBC Driver to Wildfly that can be used by WebApp

Tags: jdbc, wildfly, wildfly-10

We are currently migrating from Tomcat to Wildfly 10 server. We like to take advantages of a Java EE Server. Currently we have some issues with the DataSource. We have deployed the JDBC Driver on Wildfly and set up the DataSource.
That works mainly good, but we like to use DatabaseQueryNotification (Oracle) for database-side events.

Now the problem I run into:

When I package the Driver with my war (additionally), I get an ClassCastException because of mismatch of T4Connection and OracleConnection. Therefore I removed the JDBC-Driver from my War (maven -> scope: provided). But now my Application failed on Deployment, because of NoClassDefFound (see Stacktrace bellow).

How can I make sure that the JDBC Driver can be found by the application?

Java Snippet:

```
public class DBListener implements IDBListener, Runnable, DatabaseChangeListener, IPropertyListener, Serializable {  
     @Resource(lookup = "java:/PlsDS")  
     private DataSource dataSource;  
     ...  
     public void connectToDB(){
       Connection tmpCon = dataSource.getConnection();  
       connection = (OracleConnection) tmpCon.getMetaData().getConnection();  
       ...
     }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
14:32:59,869 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-7) Failed to define class de.istec.pls.client.db.listener.DBListener in Module "deployment.client.pls-sc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link de/istec/pls/client/db/listener/DBListener (Module "deployment.client.pls-sc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader): oracle/jdbc/dcn/DatabaseChangeListener
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadClassInfoSet(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:259)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:169)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

14:32:59,871 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."client.pls-sc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."client.pls-sc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "client.pls-sc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link de/istec/pls/client/db/listener/DBListener (Module "deployment.client.pls-sc-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader): oracle/jdbc/dcn/DatabaseChangeListener
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadClassInfoSet(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:259)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:169)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
```

Comment: You definitely don't want to package the driver in your WAR. Did you add a module for the driver or deploy the JAR? You'll likely want to create a module for it in your case.

Comment: I just deployed the JAR via Administriation Console.

Comment: JAR files deployed through admin console will be available to datasource defined in configuration files. If you want to make JDBC driver class available to webapp then you have to create module or add JDBC driver jar in Webapp classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the Problem:

1. I had to deploy the JDBC-Driver as a Module (see:
   http://hpehl.info/jdbc-driver-setup.html)
2. I have to Export the needed oracle.jdbc.dcn* files, from module
3. Insert the Dependency in the Manifest.MF file. (can be done by Maven, see below)

**module.xml**

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.oracle">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <system export="true">
        <paths>
            <path name="oracle/jdbc/OracleStatement"/>
            <path name="oracle/jdbc/dcn/DatabaseChangeEvent"/>
            <path name="oracle/jdbc/dcn/DatabaseChangeListener"/>
            <path name="oracle/jdbc/dcn/DatabaseChangeRegistration"/>
            <path name="oracle/jdbc/dcn/QueryChangeDescription"/>
            <path name="oracle/jdbc/dcn/RowChangeDescription"/>
        </paths>
    </system>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifestEntries>
             <Dependencies>com.oracle</Dependencies>
          </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score -2):

You should get an instance of a datasource through JNDI or inject through CDI.

Comment: I get the DataSource via JNDI, that's not the problem. The error says it can't find the oracle/jdbc/dcn/DatabaseChangeListener which I implement with the Class.

Comment: Irrc the connection you are getting is a org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection from which you need to get the 'real' connection

Comment: The Connection is not my Problem. The Application fails currently at Deploy-Time because it can't find the JDBC implementation, especially the DatabaseChangeListener (oracle.jdbc.dcn.DatabaseChangeListene). I need to Import sevral orcacle.jndi.dcn.* Classes, but need to recieve the Driver (jdbc7.jar) from server.

Comment: did you export (using the exports tag in the module.xml) those package when you created the module for the driver ? otherwise those are not available

Comment: This was the missing hint. Thanks!